# La modal de Bootstrap 5 no se muestra con el método modal()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Este código está ideado para mostrar una modal de Bootstrap en un documento sencillo para después poder aplicarlo a otro proyecto. Al pulsar el botón en cuestión, no me lanza ningún error pero tampoco se muestra la ventana modal. He optado por utilizar el método **modal()** de JQuery en vez del funcionamiento estándar que proporciona la página web de Bootstrap 5. Me vendría bien la ayuda. Gracias.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Ejemplo AJAX 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="miBoton">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#miBoton").click(function() {
                $("#miModal").modal();
            });
        });
        
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Porqué jQuery con Bootstrap 5? Al final estás cargando scripts duplicados, pues tienes el bundle de Bootstrap (que trae boostrap.js y popper.js juntos), y luego los estás llamando por separado, cargando cuatro scripts a la final (cinco contando jQuery que no es necesario)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas jquery debes llamar al modal de bootstrap 5 de esta forma:

```javascript
$("#miModal").modal('show');
```

para que te funcione.

Snippet de ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Ejemplo AJAX 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="miBoton">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#miBoton").click(function() {
                $("#miModal").modal('show');
            });
        });
        
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```